# Sending a form request in Python

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, button

I am trying to simulate a button click in Python on a website, when that button is clicked it adds some stuff to the end of the URL and returns false. If I add the stuff to the end of the URL it takes me to the right place but doesn't register that the button was click which is why I think I need to use the return false part.

Here is the exact code for the button and the button area. I don't know if this is actually doing anything or just setting up the button and waiting for the javascript to actually do the execution.

```
<div class="contractLink"><button  type="button" value="upgrade to level 3"id="button533e24e4d7c79" class="green build" onclick="window.location.href = 'dorf1.php?a=16&amp;c=fb5ad7'; return false;">
    <div class="button-container addHoverClick">
        <div class="button-background">
            <div class="buttonStart">
                <div class="buttonEnd">
                    <div class="buttonMiddle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-content">upgrade to level 3</div>
    </div>
</button>
```

This is where the script is that gets run when the button is clicked. I basically want to simulate the button being clicked through a python script which should go to a different URL and say "it's upgraded" (not literally say "it's upgraded" but make the website think it is and start the upgrading process)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function()
    {
    if($('button533e24e4d7c79'))
    {
        $('button533e24e4d7c79').addEvent('click', function ()
        {
            window.fireEvent('buttonClicked', [this, {"type":"button","value":"upgrade to level 3","name":"","id":"button533e24e4d7c79","class":"green build","title":"","confirm":"","onclick":"window.location.href = \u0027dorf1.php?a=16\u0026amp;c=fb5ad7\u0027; return false;"}]);
        });
    }
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be great, thanks for your time.

Comment: Does your solution have to be in python?  Would you be open to using a solution in jquery?

Comment: I planned on making a program with a GUI that had options and would send these types of forms/requests etc. So in whatever language I can make that happen in is the one I'm going to use :)

Comment: Ok, I know how to easily do this in JQuery and using an HTML5-based GUI.  I'm sure there's solutions in python too, with urllib or something, but I'm drawing a blank for that.

Comment: How easily would it be to make a GUI with JQuery? I planned on having this be a standalone from the browser is that still possible with JQuery or no? I really only want interaction with the website when I'm getting/sending requests.

Comment: If you develop the GUI with HTML5 and CSS styling, you can run in any browser that supports HTML5. I believe you can create standalone HTML5 apps (App.js I think will do the trick).

Comment: Alright that sounds like it would work, I have no knowledge of JQuery so this should be fun. What is your solution?

Comment: So, suppose your submit button has an id "submit". In Jquery, all you would do is: $("#submit").trigger("click");  (you can test this in the Google Chrome Console --> Ctrl+Shift+J ).  That will mimick a submit button click event, with only one line of code.

Comment: So in my case with the button id "button533e24e4d7c79" I'd do: $("#button533e24e4d7c79").trigger("click"); is the # needed before the actual id?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.  Here's a very simplified example at JSfiddle I just created: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkUbS/1/  (I'll update it to match your id)

Comment: I just tried it and got an error : cannot call trigger method of null

Comment: updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkUbS/2/  (I moved the trigger call into the js frame so you don't need to use the google chrome console)

Comment: I tried doing the setup you said with chrome and am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of null

Comment: Oh, it seems like Jquery is not normally included in that JSfiddle website.  But, what I've managed to do is update the JSfiddle so you can see that immediately invoked function triggering the click.  I'll try to update the JSfiddle with some comments to clarify.

Comment: Basically, if you had the html and javascript saved in a file on your computer, and included <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js"></script> before the </body> tag, it would work in the console.

Comment: Well the problem is when I try and try it on the actual webpage instead of the JSfiddle, the only thing I can think of is that even though when I inspect the button element and get the id, that is not the correct id. Where I'm trying to use it my id = "button533e309f25c89" and I try running $("#button533e309f25c89").trigger("click"); and end up with the error, TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of null. So the only think I can think of is if that button doesn't exist under that name, or the trigger can't "click" this button?

Comment: I just tried it again, instead of trigger I used: $("#button533e309f25c89").click(); and that seemed to work just fine. Is that a reliable way to do it or would it be better to try and do something with trigger? Also, one thing I should mention is that I personally do not have the code to this site, it is a site online that I am trying to make a program for. So how would I have it run if I just gave it the URL and then the $("#button533e309f25c89").click();

Comment: Here, let's forget JSFiddle..it's complicating things.  Here's what I meant.  I posted the full code on Gist: https://gist.github.com/richardeschloss/d4d27b0c19cf86b5caba  --> Save that off to an html file, and then when you open it in the google chrome console the triggering works (with: $("#button533e24e4d7c79").trigger("click"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative to using Python; this might be useful to those wishing to have a button click simulation without having normal subsequent action take place at the testers discretion.

Assuming that the id of the button to be simulated is "button533e24e4d7c79", the jQuery library has the trigger method to trigger the click (or any supported event for that matter) of this button:

```
$("#button533e24e4d7c79").trigger("click"); // This will mimic the clicking of the button (programmatically) -- requires Jquery
```

My understanding is that the trigger method will invoke the "click" event and stop at the event handler (i.e., won't follow links, won't continue with form submission, etc.).  I haven't fully tested, but that's my understanding.

If it's desired to fully simulate the button click, jquery.simulate.js library (https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js) provides the simulate method to allow following of links, etc.

The jQuery learning page at http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/ provides the proper explanation.

Comment: Welp.. I can't even upvote because I don't have enough reputation... Someone upvote this guy! He was insanely helpful!